# Arbitary depth queries in arangodb?

Tags: neo4j, arangodb

I was working in a problem where i need arbitrary depth relations between nodes ,

```
For v,e,p in 1..2 INBOUND 'emps/1386821' GRAPH 'Heirarchy'
     OPTIONS { bfs : true} 
     return p
```

The above query is fixed for depth of min 1 and max 2, but can i do

```
1..*
```

Type of queries where max can be any length, as provided by Neo4j
Cypher Query Language

```
Match (n:Emp{ name : "Manager"})<-[:ReportsTo *]-(m:Emp) Return m
```

Answer (score 1):

An arbitrary depth can not be specified directly, but you can set some high number:

```
FOR v, e, p in 1..9999 INBOUND 'emps/1386821' GRAPH 'Heirarchy'
     OPTIONS { bfs: true }
     RETURN p
```

Note that high traversal depths can mean very high computational complexity. This is especially true if you follow edges in `ANY` direction. It depends a lot on your dataset, whether such a query can still be answered in a reasonable time or take forever because of exponential complexity.